# nested if else python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-behave

I am not sure why the following code is not working. Actually even after matching all 3 if conditions, the code is not able to reach the assertion statements inside the last if block

I have validated and printed the required data for the same and by looking , I did not find any data discrepancies. Where it went wrong?

```
def step_impl(context, status, exp_date, owner, reg_date, man_yr, vchl_make, vchl_code):
    if exp_date < context.end_date:
        if reg_date > '01-09-2018':
            if man_yr == context.expctd_manu_year:
                assert int(context.json_response[0]['base_premium']) > int(1)
                assert int(context.json_response[0]['total_premium']) > int(1)
                assert int(context.json_response[0]['tax']) > int(1)
                print(context.json_response[0]["tax"])
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

Data:
context.end_date = 12-12-2021
context.expctd_manu_year = 2018
exp_date = 30-10-2021
reg_date = 10-09-2018
man_yr = 2018
context.expctd_manu_year = 2018
```

Comment: `reg_date > '01-09-2018'` is not how you compare dates. Or maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Add *print()* statements for the 4 variables that you're testing. Also, none of the *else:* statements are necessary. It's also possible that assertions are disabled if Python is being run with the -O option

Comment: Output of print statement ---- context.end_date = 12-12-2021
context.expctd_manu_year = 2018
exp_date = 30-10-2021
reg_date = 10-09-2018
man_yr = 2018
context.expctd_manu_year = 2018

Comment: So you're making lexical comparisons on dates in DD-MM-YYYY format. That won't work. If they were YYYY-MM-DD then that would work

Comment: Not only assertions, it is not able to reach the print statement also just below the last assertion statement

Comment: @ApratimChaudhuri That's because the conditions are not being met. See my previous comment regarding date formats and lexical comparisons

Comment: Then what is the work around if DD-MM-YYYY does not work?

Comment: The exp_date and Reg_date is directly coming from json payload. So if I change the format, the payload will not accept the data for the post API request

Comment: `else: pass` is redundant. You don't need an else clause on every if statement.

Comment: @ApratimChaudhuri Take a look at datetime.strptime Also, you could just rearrange the string into an appropriate format and still do your lexical comparison

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on lexical comparisons between dates and your original date strings are guaranteed to be formatted as DD-MM-YYYY then you could do this:

```
def fix(d):
    return d[6:]+d[2:6]+d[:2]

da = '31-01-2021'
db = '02-02-2021'

assert fix(da) < fix(db)
```